# Changing the HTML of notices in WooCommerce

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, templates, e-commerce, notices

I'm creating a WooCommerce theme from scratch, and I'd really like to change the HTML that wraps the default WooCommerce messages on the `Cart` and `Checkout` pages.

I am specifically talking about the default messages that appear in this element, when the cart is updated - or items are removed:

```
<div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">
        Your cart has been updated / Product was removed. Undo? 
</div>
```

I have tried several things;

1. I am overriding the default `error.php`, `success.php` and `notice.php` templates in the `templates/notices` folder. These, I concluded, were seemingly only used for *some* of these notifications. My errors use the error template just fine, for example.
2. I tracked, what I thought was the culprit, down to the function `woocommerce_output_all_notices` in the `wc-template-functions.php` file. I was almost sure that this was it, since it was the only function that I could find, being called inside the wrapping container (The `<div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper">` element).

The function looks like this:

```
function woocommerce_output_all_notices() {
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper">';
    wc_print_notices();
    echo '</div>';
}
```

It would be logical to think, that the markup is then coming from the `wc_print_notices()` function.

However, when I look at this function in `wc-notice-functions.php`... It uses the templates that I mentioned in #1.. ?

What am I doing wrong here? Does anyone have experience with properly altering the markup of these message?

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with some of the WooCommerce people on Slack, I realized that the problem here is *probably* [this pattern](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0d59195657c70b8d01a8b6c0ac13a0abb6c5f209/assets/js/frontend/cart.js#L157), in `frontend/cart.js` - due to the fact, that my store uses the AJAX functionality that WooCommerce provides.

```
var show_notice = function( html_element, $target ) {
        if ( ! $target ) {
            $target = $( '.woocommerce-notices-wrapper:first' ) ||
                $( '.cart-empty' ).closest( '.woocommerce' ) ||
                $( '.woocommerce-cart-form' );
        }
        $target.prepend( html_element );
```

A default, new HTML element seems to be created and prepended to the wrapper when certain store states are met after an AJAX update.